# Automatically save a Word document as a PDF using VBA while extracting specific values

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to select 3 values from one page of a word document and save a document as a pdf under those names.
For example: In the second line of the document there is only the Surname (father's name) and the person's first name, further on sometimes in the fifth lines, sometimes in the sixth line is the specific location and finally further on in the text there is a specific code.
My intention is to use code to find those three values and save that document under those values.

I start with this:

```
Sub test1()
  Dim dlgFile As FileDialog

  Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
 
  Set dlgFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

  With dlgFile
    If .Show = -1 Then
      strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    Else
      MsgBox "Select a folder!"
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End With
 
  For nSectionNum = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToNext, Name:=nSectionNum
    ActiveDocument.Sections(nSectionNum).Range.Copy
 
    Set objDocAdded = Documents.Add
    Selection.Paste
 
Dim strFileName As String
Set rngFilename = objDocAdded.Range
With rngFilename
    .End = .Start
    .MoveEnd wdWord, 4
    strFileName = .Text
End With
objDocAdded.SaveAs "E:\test\" & strFileName & ".docx"
    objDocAdded.Close
  Next nSectionNum
 End Sub
```

With this code I save a word document with the name of the first 4 words at the beginning of the document.
MONICA (George) HENDERSON
I got this
[image]
I want this
[image]

Comment: *...further on sometimes in the fifth lines, sometimes in the sixth line is the specific location...* Why don't I see these examples and code that you requested? Can you explain it more clearly? And as you have shown the top two files, their names after the  "MONICA (George) HENDERSON"  is what meaning? Where are they from?

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted with this code:

```
Dim srchRng As Range
Dim rngLine2 As Word.Range, rngLine5 As Word.Range
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

Set rngLine2 = ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs(2).Range
Set rngLine5 = ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs(5).Range
Set srchRng = ActiveDocument.Content

With rngLine2
    .End = .Start
    .MoveEnd wdWord, 5
    rngFilename = .Text
End With

a = rngFilename

With rngLine5
    .End = .Start
    .MoveEnd wdWord, 3
    rngFilename = .Text
End With

b = rngFilename


With srchRng.Find
    .Text = "CD:"
    .Execute
    If .Found = True Then
        Dim numberStart As Long
        numberStart = Len(srchRng.Text) + 1
        srchRng.MoveEndUntil Cset:=","

        Dim myNum As String
        myNum = Mid(srchRng.Text, numberStart)
    End If
End With
c = myNum

For nSectionNum = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToNext, Name:=nSectionNum
ActiveDocument.Sections(nSectionNum).Range.Copy
 
Set objDocAdded = Documents.Add
Selection.Paste

objDocAdded.SaveAs "E:\test\" & "Sample " & a & b & c & ".docx"
objDocAdded.Close
Next nSectionNum
  
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="E:\test\" & "Sample " & a & b & c & ".pdf", _
ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

Is this complicated or could it be simpler?
The most important thing is that I got what I wanted, the only thing is that I should directly save the document as a pdf, and not save it as a word document and then save it as a pdf.

Comment: You are too general in your description of what you want to achieve, for example, why use "Sections" object to iterate? And you ignored my previous questions also, and just threw out the code and told people to read it (with errors still), which is not a good attitude to ask. Since you have already achieved what you want, I'll just skip the quiz.

Comment: I apologize if I was rude, it won't happen again in the future. I will be much more specific when looking for a solution.